# Unable to get work history/ email and other information

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a list of user id's ( may or may not be my friends) I want to get ALL the public possible information about them.. However, I am only getting back Name, Id and Photo. Where am I going wrong?

```
        FB.login(function(){
      /* make the API call */
        FB.api(
            "/{event-id}/attending",
            function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {

                var array = response.data;

                array.forEach(function(eachUser){
                    //console.log(eachUser);

                FB.api(
                        "/"+ eachUser.id,
                        function (response) {
                          if (response && !response.error) {
                            console.log(response);
                          }
                        }
                    );
                });

              }
            }
        );
    }, {scope: 'user_events, user_education_history , user_about_me , user_work_history , user_location , user_website'}); //,age_range, bio , context , education
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it´s set to public, all the other data is only available if the user authorizes your App with the appropriate permission. So in the list of attending users, name/id/photo is the only data you can get.